# "Application tried to present modally an active controller" iOS8 - When i want to present an AlertView in logging out

Tags: swift, ios8, swift2, alertview

Well, I am really a beginner in terms of swift 2 and I am having an error in `presentViewController`, this is just an alert view before logging out. But I am receiving an application tried to present modally an active conroller. Well I have a menu bar using the `SWRevealViewController` and `MenuBarTableViewController` class that holds the menu bar. `Logout` button was on the last selection of the menu bar, and I am browsing every single menu and it works fine but this `Logout AlertView` makes it to crash and gets that error. Here is the code.

```
class MenuBarTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    private struct PMText {
       static let logoutBody = "Are you sure you want to log out?"
    }

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Logout", message: PMText.logoutBody, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
             title: "No",
             style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
        { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
             //do nothing just to close the alertView
            }
        )

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
             title: "Yes",
             style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        { (action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
             self.performSegueWithIdentifier("log out", sender: nil)
            }
        )

        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
         for index in 0..<tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section) {
         let cellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: index, inSection: indexPath.section)
         let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(cellIndexPath)!
         if index == indexPath.row {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 254/255, green: 255/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1)
         } else {
             cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         }


         if (indexPath.row == 6) {
             presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
       }
    }



}
```

Well I am not sure what makes my code crash and received this kind of exception since I am doing Alert View Controller a lot of times in my other View Controller. But this is the first time i tried this in `MenuBarTableViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out a solution for this by creating a plain swift file for menubar using the SWReveal rather than creating a cocoa touch file. So it will now `import Foundation` rather than `import UIKit`. It is having trouble with the menu bar slider because the slider is considered as controller when it is a cocoa touch and the AlertView is another view controller to be presented.